# How to apply styles for root & child elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to apply styles for root and child elements separately by CSS.

```css
 
.animals{

    background-color: bisque;
}

.pets{

    background-color: rgb(160, 5, 180);
}

.small{

    background-color: rgb(68, 255, 155);
}

.big{

    background-color: rgb(255, 68, 208);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <ul class="animals">
            <li>Forest</li>
            <li>
                <ul class="pets">
                    <li>
                        <ul class="small">
                            <li>Rabbit</li>
                            <li>Squirral</li>
                            <li>
                                <ul class="small">
                                    <li>
                                        <ul class="small">
                                            <li>Rabbit</li>
                                            <li>Squirral</li>
                                            <li>Cat</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <ul class="big">
                    <li>Dog</li>
                    <li>Cow</li>
                    <li>Horse</li>
                    <li>Elephent</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

From above code, The list structure is 3 level `ul`

```
<ul> <!-- level 1, name: sub1 -->
   <li>
       <ul> <!-- level 2, name: sub1 -->
           <li>
               <ul> <!-- level 3, name: sub2 -->
                   <li>
                        <ul></ul> <!-- level N, name: sub2 -->
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

From above code, sub1 will have multiple, multi level sub2 only. So, I don't like to use classes for this constant structural list. I am curious to study some thing like `first-child` type of selector in CSS.

I have to apply styles by below way

1. Apply styles for `level 1` only
2. Apply styles for level 2 only
3. Apply styles for level 3 only
4. Apply styles for `level 2 & level 2` combined.

How can I use CSS to apply styles without `id` and `class`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Only a `<li>` can be the child of a `<ul>`.

Comment: @Rob, Fixed & Updated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. You can use the "element" "element" selector of css.
Example:

```
ul {
    /*Style lvl 1 ul*/
    color: red;
}
ul ul {
    /*Style lvl 2 ul*/
    color: green;
}

ul ul ul {
    /*Style lvl 3 ul*/
    color: blue;
}


ul ul {
    /*Style lvl 2 + 3 ul*/
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

CSS choice the latest information of the same importance.

Here can you look for CSS-Selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp